# Succinct way to respond to user input?

Tags: bash, read

Of course you can do this sort of thing,

```
read var; if [[ $var = 'y' ]]; then echo "Yes"; fi
```

But is there any way to skip the first step and do something a little more like this, (ideally without needing a subshell):

```
if [[ $(read var) = 'y' ]]; then echo "Yes"; fi
```

Of course the above doesn't work unless you add `echo`, but I'm looking for something much cleaner and simpler than this:

```
if [[ $(read var; echo "$var") = 'y' ]]; then echo "Yes"; fi
```

It would be ideal if this would work:

```
if [[ read = 'y' ]]; then echo "Yes"; fi
```

Comment: `read && printf '\a'` is pretty succinct and is bound to make your application a popular one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a function to do what you need:

```
user_input () {
    read var
    echo $var
}
if [ "$(user_input)" = 'y' ]; then echo "Yes"; fi
```

At the top I define a function called user_input, which will read the value in, and then echo it out.  Then the if statement is able to take that value and check if it is 'y'.  I've wrapped the `$(user_input)` in quotation marks in case the user put in spaces, so that the script doesn't just error out.

Comment: Yes:  if I change the name of the function to something like `user_input` then the resulting code reads quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is still too long for what you had in mind:

```
read foo && [ "$foo" = 'y' ] && echo 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
read -q && echo yes
```

(see also `-s` to suppress the echo of the `y` or `n` you type).